# Переменная как название массива

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как-нибудь задать название массива значением переменной?

Проблема вообще в том,что мне нужно сделать нормальную нумерацию и идентификаторы полей созданных вот такой функцией :

```
function AddItem1(dob) {

    iddob = dob.id;
    n = parseInt(iddob.substr(3));

    k++;

    var div=document.getElementById("pole"+n);

    trs = document.createElement("TR");
    trs.setAttribute("align", "center");
    tdnazvpole = document.createElement("TD");
    tdnazvpole.setAttribute("align", "right");
    tdnazvpole.setAttribute("class", "white1");
    tdpoletest = document.createElement("TD");
    tddelbutpoletest = document.createElement("TD");
    tdnazvpole.innerHTML = "Поле "+n+ k +""; //Вывод нумерации поля
    tdpoletest.innerHTML = '<TEXTAREA required cols="10%" Rows="1"  id="na['+k+']" Name="nazva['+k+']" Maxlength="200"class="inputform"></TEXTAREA>'; //Вывод поля
    tddelbutpoletest.innerHTML='<BUTTON type="button" id="del'+k+'"Value="' + k + '" style="height:25px; font-size:10px; line-height:1;" onClick="delRowTes(this)">-</BUTTON>'; //Вывод кнопки "Удалить"

    trs.appendChild(tdnazvpole);
    trs.appendChild(tdpoletest); //вывод форм
    trs.appendChild(tddelbutpoletest);
    div.appendChild(trs);
}
```

До этой функции создаётся кнопка +,которая и вызывает функцию,передавая ей свой параметр.
Вся загвоздка в том,что при создании полей в разных div нумерация идёт не отдельно,а продолжается из одного в другой.

Comment: а в чем смысл такого..хм..странного решения?

Comment: так что-ли ? http://ideone.com/efdCOy

Comment: Вроде да.Только как это на javascript реализовать?

Comment: я выше исправил ответ, лучше не делать этого на самом деле, просто сделайте приложение нормальным. покажите кусок кода где  вам это понадобилось, весьма вероятно вам хватит что-то типа

     var arrays={a: [1,2,3,4],b: [10,20,30,40]};
     key='a';
     console.log (arrays[key]);
     key='b';
     console.log (arrays[key]);

Comment: Есть один способ, но его использовать не стоит ни в коем случае:
    
    name = "arrName";
    eval('var ' + name + ' = []');

Comment: изменил вопрос,может там что подскажите,раз с массивом ерунда.
Была вообще идея записывать в массив id кнопки добавления полей.В новом div своя кнопка.При повторных нажатиях на кнопку проверять нажималась она или нет,если нет то создавать массив с названием у которого название будет id кнопки,а в этом массиве хранить количество полей созданных в этом div,что бы потом при нажатии на кнопку с этим id проверялось сколько полей создано

Comment: @Ринат Давлетбаев а массив где ? упростите немного код и мб сделайте [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) чтобы явно было видно что не получается.

Comment: Да вы правильно меня поняли.Про массив я выше написал. Div это тело(таблица) в котором у меня динамически создаются поля

Comment: var k=div.childNodes.length;

Comment: Капец оказывается всё просто!!!Спасибо большое.Может посоветуете какую-нибудь книгу по js?

Answer (score 3):

Есть несколько решений.

Первое и наиболее правильное, использовать для хранения данных специальный объект, к котором и обращаться. В этом случае можно использовать переменную очевидным образом:

```
a[varName]
```

Если нужна именно переменная, то в зависимости от того переменная локальна или глобальна, у вас есть несколько вариантов:

```
window[varName]
```

для глобальных и

```
eval(varName)
```

для локальных, но это не очень безопасно, и ни в коем случае не должно использоваться, если varName вы не контроллируете. Вообще этот способ лучше никогда не использовать, а просто знать о том, что он есть.

Answer (score 0):

Если переменная глобальная (или метод объекта):

```
window[nameVar] = [];
```

Если локальная - без eval никак.